# Opening a file within unclosed file pointer

Tags: c, file-pointer

Is it possible to open a file using an fopen () function within an already opened but not closed fopen () command? And what is the consequence of that if i do need to do so?

Sample: 
     .
     .
     .

```
l_file_ptr = fopen (l_inp_file, "r");
if (l_file_ptr == 0)  fatal_err("Could not open l_inp_file", -1);
    for (n_sph = 0; n_sph < num_sph; n_sph++) 
    {
       sph = &objects[n_sph];
       fscanf (l_file_ptr, "%d %le", &sph->num_surface_node, &sph->r_c);

       sph->surfnode = (struct nodalpoint *) calloc(num_sursph, sizeof(*(sph->surfnode)));
          if (sph->surfnode == 0 ) fatal_err("cannot allocate boundary nodes", -1);
            file_ptr = fopen (s_inp_file, "r");
            if(file_ptr == 0)  fatal_err("Could not open s_inp_file", -1);
               for (n_surp = 0; n_surp < num_sursph; n_surp++)   
               {
               fscanf (file_ptr, "%le",&sph->surfnode[n_surp].x);
               }
            fclose (file_ptr);
            file_ptr = 0;
   }
   fclose (l_file_ptr);
   l_file_ptr = 0;
```

following this part of my code i found out that information doesn't transferred properly.
My guess: Do you this this could be a problem of buffer or the nested file opening process.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use rewind to reset the file pointer to the beginning. You can't open an already opened file.

Comment: @Brandin who told you that `You can't open an already opened file`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with opening an already opened file. However, don't do it here because there is no need.

Comment: Mind you! There are two file pointers , l_file_ptr and file_ptr. l_file_ptr kept open until the second file pointer file_ptr finished reading. Finally. l_file_ptr get closed.

Comment: Thanks Brandin!, I solve my problem based on the notion you mentioned.